# Coldfusion MVC framework with crud for many-mamy

Tags: frameworks, coldfusion, many-to-many, crud

I've spent the last couple of months on and off with CFwhees.

There's a lot it has going for simplicity, but I always come up against an issue or two that I have a hard time troubleshooting. Biggest of them is to get a many-many relationship to work properly.

I'm switching between two environments Railo/mySQL and CF/MsSQL so it would be nice if it could work on both.

I'm trying to roll out a web application in a limited amount of time, as I've spent already too much time on CF wheels.

Can anyone recommend a framework that will make creating many-many relationships and the related CRUD easy and has a big community?

Some of the one's I've seen mentioned frequently are MachII, FuseBox, Model-Glue, ColdBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of those frameworks you list do not have built-in ORM like wheels does.  This means you'll be either using straight SQL queries or the CF9(Hibernate) ORM.  I think it is only fair to mention that both of those options are also available for CFWheels.

I've written a fairly large app in CFWheels.  In my app there were several instances of many-to-many relationships, and I was able to make it work without too much pain.  That being said, I have felt your frustration with the CFWheels ORM.  It can be clunky once you get to complex relationships.  In those cases, I've had to make a judgement call as to whether it was worth it to try to build a query using the ORM, or just build a custom SQL query and store it in the CFC for my model.  In fact, for 99% of my report queries for this app, I just resorted to writing the SQL in the model.   But for CRUD operations, this wasn't really a limiting factor.

I'm curious what specific problems you're experiencing with Wheels - care to post an example?

Comment: http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/nested-properties   Many-to-Many   just can't get it to work. Knowing that someone else is having issues does make me feel a little less incompetent.

Comment: I've read that page, quite a few times.  But I don't know exactly what you're having trouble with.  One thing that I'll mention (as it wasn't real obvious to me) is the syntax for joining multiple tables:model("Foo").findAll(include="Join1(Join2)");  If you'd like more explanation for that, let me know and I can elaborate.

Comment: I've added it as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275830/many-to-many-relationship-with-cfwheels

Comment: Not sure if I am doing the right thing here.. but the discussion board on cfwheels google group is very active and the core cfwheels team are incredibly helpful with any problems.  Just go to the cfwheels website, then community, and Discussion Group.. one of the most helpful community I have ever come across.

Answer (score 2):

yes the orm in cfwheels can be buggy at times. if you encounter a bug or even what you **THINK** might be a bug, we want to know. please take the time to file a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/cfwheels/issues/list) so we can investigate. that all being said, i'm very surprised that the CF community hasn't taken noticed about Don Humphrey's ORM called [CFRel](https://github.com/dhumphreys/cfrel). It's probably one of the biggest things to happen to CFML since fusebox.

Oh... and there is even a [cfwheels plugin for it](http://cfwheels.org/plugins/listing/68).

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't have much experience with rails, so a lot of the things that seem second nature to some is getting me confused, like using the right case(plural/singular) is confusing to me still. Also seems like the documentation is for 1.1, but the current version is 1.6, and resources like mr Hanke's handy collection looks like it's a bit different from the documentation.